# Access - Strange Error with Date Function

Tags: datetime, ms-access

This is a strange bug and I feel like I'm missing something easy.

When I use the standard access date function on one form it works without issue (see 'functions properly').  When I use it on another form (see 'code causing error') I get a debug error 'Database can't find the field 'Date' referred to in your expression.'

Hoping someone else sees a stupid/obvious mistake...

**Functions properly:**

```
With rs
    .AddNew
    If chkSubAssembly = True Then
        .Fields("Document") = mySubassembly
        .Fields("Type") = "S"
    Else
        .Fields("Document") = "M" & cmbCustomer & "-" & txtCustPN
        .Fields("Type") = "D"
    End If
    .Fields("Description") = txtDMRDesc
    .Fields("Author") = Forms("frmUser").lblUser.Caption
    .Fields("CreationDate") = date
    .Fields("Revision") = "Draft"
    .Fields("PE") = cmbPE.Column(1)
    .Fields("lasteditby") = Forms("frmUser").lblUser.Caption
    .Update
End With
```

**Code Causing Error:**

```
With rs
    .AddNew
    .Fields("ValidNum") = myProtocol
    .Fields("Description") = txtNewDescription
    .Fields("Author") = Forms("frmUser").lblUser.Caption
    .Fields("createdOn") = date
    .Fields("lasteditby") = Forms("frmUser").lblUser.Caption
    .Update
End With
```

Comment: It is recommended that code is pasted in the question rather than using images, that way peers can copy paste to replicate. Otherwise one would lose interest to typeout by looking at the images.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  I updated the post accordingly.

Comment: You could try using `DateTime.Date` or `now` to help track down what's going on.  You may want to use `now` in order to get the time as well as day.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JimB , changing it to datetime.date did resolve the issue.  I still have no idea why 'Date' works in one form but I need to explicitly call out 'datetime.date' in another form of the same database.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't make sense that access would treat date as a field name. You may want to compact and repair the database and see if it cleans up some old references.

Comment: Sometimes in a situation like this you can create an empty database and import just the form and related objects (tables,queries) and see if that resolves the problem.  That would indicate that the internal data that access uses to represent the objects and their relationships got corrupted.

Comment: Do you have a control and/or field on the form named "date"?  Within the VBA editor press F2 or go to View | Object Browser.  Now search for "date".  Scroll through the results looking for the name or path of your Access file in the Library column.  It should reveal if something in your file is named "date".

Comment: @CPerkins that's a good thought and I had something similar.  The error code makes it sound like Access is looking for a control or field in a query.  I did a search through my form and found nothing called 'date'.  All the controls have prefixes indicating type ('txt' 'btn', 'lst' etc) and even the dataset for the form doesn't have anything called 'date'.

Comment: @CZandstra  Okay, I'm glad you already considered that, but there is still something obviously interfering with the name resolution.  What's not clear is how you did your search.  Just manually?  Sorry for being persistent, but I have no idea of the complexities or details of your forms, code or data.  In other words, did you go ahead and do what I suggested in the Object Browser despite what you searched for in the past?